# Need to know the exact differences between the docker, rocket and CRIO

Tags: docker, rocket, cri-o

We have docker, rocket and CRIO as OCIs .

what is the main differences between docker , rocket and CRIO ?

why only docker is most popular ? what is the reason behind the same ?

Anticipating your responses

what is the main differences between docker , rocket and CRIO ?

why only docker is most popular ? what is the reason behind the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Rocket is no longer supported.
The alternative to Docker is Podman, which is very popular.

CRI-O is a competitor to containerd for running containers under kubernetes.

Podman and Docker have the same CLI and Podman supports the Docker API.

Just google Podman and you will find hundreds of articles on it.